# php rand function i want to skip 1 int and have a random number between 4 integers

Tags: php, random

I want to do something like this
 `$ticket = rand(1,44 & 46,89);`

I have tried

```
$ticket = rand(44,46);

if($ticket === 45){

}elseif($ticket === 90){

}else{
    rand(1,90);
}
```

Still sitting with the problem that 45 and 90 comes forth

I want random numbers but want to skip the int 45

Comment: `$n=rand(1,88); if ($n>44) $n++;`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That means the odds is 2/90 that the number is 45.

Comment: the problem is i will submit the random lottery everytime so 45 musnt come forth not even once

Comment: @Andreas [nonsense](https://ideone.com/fHw5yQ)

Comment: I see that I missread your code. I read it as if =45 n++. I see that you now mean if >44 n++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give a random number of 1->89 where all numbers are equally likely to happen.
If it's 45 just do another rand().

```
$true = true;

while($true){
    $ticket = rand(1,89);
    if($ticket != 45) $true = !$true;
}

echo $ticket;
```

https://3v4l.org/BaRht